# Search for Longest strings in Multi Blocks

Tags: html, jquery

I have 2 blocks of code and search for a longest string in each block appearing on each alert. obviously, `wonderful` is longest string in the block 1 and `beautiful` is longest string in block 2.

`wonderful` should be in first alert and `beautiful` should be in second alert, but somehow I miss something.  Please give me a hand.

Thanks!

```js
$('.parent').each(function() {
  longest = "";
  $('.child').each(function() {
    var textChild = $(this).text();
    if (textChild.length > longest.length) {
      longest = textChild;
    }
  });
  alert(longest)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">hello</div>
  <div class="child">wonderful</div>
  <div class="child">world</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">hello</div>
  <div class="child">beautiful</div>
  <div class="child">world</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `map()` to build an array of the text content of the `.child` elements within each `.parent`, then you can use `reduce()` to get the longest of them.

Note that you need to output the `longest` value within the loop. Try this:

```js
$('.parent').each(function() {
  let longest = $(this).find('.child').map((i, el) => el.textContent.trim()).get().reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
  console.log(longest);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">hello</div>
  <div class="child">wonderful</div>
  <div class="child">world</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">hello</div>
  <div class="child">beautiful</div>
  <div class="child">world</div>
</div>
```

If you want to get the longest values outside of the loop, then I'd suggest pushing them to their own array which you can iterate through as required.